# Create a loop to check out results

Tags: php

I have a DB structure like this and i need to check out folder and document end date from box

```
BOX
box_id
box_title
box_end_date

FOLDER
folder_id
folder_box_id
folder_end_date

DOCUMENT
document_id
document_folder_id
document_end_date
```

To check out folder date I use:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM folder WHERE folder_end_date != '0000-00-00' AND box_id='$box_id'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows > 0) {
    echo 'OK';
} else {
    echo 'KO';
}
```

Now, I need to check out all document_end_date. I assume box can contain many folders and folders can many documents.

Please, can anyone help me to create a loop to check out this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through the data you get from the query:

```
foreach($row AS mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['folder_end_date'];
}
```

But you should really be using the new [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).